# Getting "Access Denied" in AWS lambda "Edit runtime settings"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Few days ago I received an email that python2.7 is going to be deprecated in AWS lambda, so I'm trying to change the runtime to python3.8. But when doing it, I receive an "Access denied" error. I also cannot update de source code, nor deploy because I receive a 403 error.

I really don't understand. My user has AdministratorAccess and I already tried giving directly LambdaFullAccess permission and nothing works, do you guys have any idea or had a similar experience?

[image: Access denied]
[image: User permissions]

## Updates

[image]

Comment: Double-check that the user trying to update the Lambda function actually has AdministratorAccess. Check any deny statements in other policies on this user or in policies inherited from group membership. Check the Lambda function's resource policy.

Comment: Check your AWS Health or emails for any security notifications. One way you get such errors as yours is if AWS limited permissions on your account due to it being compromised, or at least AWS thinking it was compromized..

Comment: As a test, are you able to create a _new_ AWS Lambda function with those settings?

Comment: I checked all things that @jarmod suggested and no luck.

Comment: Also couldn't find any notification in my email as @Marcin said.

Comment: And I cannot create new functions @JohnRotenstein

Comment: @JoseEnrique Is this your own account, or part of some AWS organization?

Comment: @Marcin it isn't the root account, it is part of an organization.

Comment: @JoseEnrique So your AWS Org can limit the permissions. You would have to check with who ever is responsible for it.

Answer (score 0):

It fixed by itself today, I tried again after some weeks. I didn't change anything. I manage the Org account as well, so no clue. Maybe it was an error on the AWS side.

It wasn't critical for us, that's why we didn't contact AWS support, but if your are in a hurry, you should contact them.